# Alternative formulas for the volume of an n-ball

Tags: volume, pi

The volume of an n-ball is

> \begin{align}\dfrac{\pi^{n/2}r^n}{\Gamma\left(n/2+1\right)}\end{align}

However if we define $\alpha = \sqrt{\pi}$, and use the $\Pi$-function, we get

> \begin{align}\dfrac{\left(\alpha r\right)^n}{\Pi(n/2)}\end{align}

which is simpler. However, this form isn't very useful, as it's not very easy to calculate $\Pi()$ of half integers.

Another formula, given $\eta = \pi/2$ and the diameter $d = 2r$, is

> \begin{align}\dfrac{d^n\eta^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}}{n!!}\end{align}

This is simpler to calculate, but it's not as pretty as it uses the diameter. Both of these functions also uses half integers; are there any functions without half integers and using $r$ which are simple to calculate?

Comment: What is your definition of  *simple to calculate*? IMO $\Gamma(n/2+1)$ is simpler than the double-factorial $n!!$. BTW, I guess the $d^2$ in your last formula should be $d^n.$

Comment: @gammatester fixed the $d^n$. The double factorial involves multiplication of integers, while $\Gamma()$ of half integers is a bit more complicated.

Comment: So your definition of simple seems to be: Using a calculator with $+,-,*, /, \sqrt{\cdot}?$

Comment: @gammatester $+,-,\times,/$. $\sqrt{}()$ could be avoided by choosing a better constant $-$ a constant that might require $\sqrt{}()$ to calculate.

Comment: I still do not get it. Why do you allow complicated constants, but not the diameter? And why don't you use
$$\frac{2^nr^n\eta^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}}{n!!}$$

Comment: @gammatester I suppose that would work, although I'd prefer $\dfrac{\left(2r\right^n\eta^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor})}{n!!}$, and I was hoping there was a way to get rid of the $2r$ without using $d$, although I guess there isn't...